# How to traverse parent dom elements and get the id in JUnit 4 Webdriver?

Tags: testing, selenium, junit4

I was curious to know if it is possible? I want to go 3 step up of a "Some Text" inside span
and grab the id of a li item which holds it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think xpath would be the way to go on this.  Something like

```
string testQuizID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'TestQuiz')]/ancestor::li[1]")).getAttribute("id");
```

I'm not sure what language you're using, this is java syntax.

Comment: xpath is slower, would be better if its possible by css?, thanks anyways!

Comment: I'd have to see the HTML in question to be sure.  In the case you've described, there's two things that point to xpath instead of CSS.  1. You want to test for contains text, and 2. You want to find a parent node.  CSS cannot perform either function, I believe.

Comment: <li id="module-33980" class="activity quiz modtype_quiz ">
<div class="mod-indent">
<div class="activityinstance">
<a class="" href="https://moodle-testing.uleth.ca/201303/mod/quiz/view.php?id=33980" onclick="">
<img class="iconlarge activityicon" role="presentation" alt=" " src="https://moodle-testing.uleth.ca/201303/theme/image.php/uofl_boot/quiz/1389995841/icon">
<span class="instancename">TestQuiz</span>
</a>
</div>
<form class="togglecompletion" action="https://moodle-testing.uleth.ca/201303/course/togglecompletion.php" method="post">
</div>
</li>

Comment: I need that test quiz's top most parent li's id.

Comment: @NawshadFarruque, you are therefore stuck to XPath selectors.

Comment: This idea that Xpath is slow and CSS is always better isn't correct with today's modern browsers' https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/pugZh1AXVMU